# Helm Range List vs Tuple

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I wonder in helm what is the difference between **range list** and **range tuple**.

I see in the official doc the use of tuple and sometime list, but i can't figure out the difference between the two. Can someone clarify ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helm relies on a support library called [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) to provide many of its template functions.  Neither the Helm nor the Sprig documentation explicitly mentions a `tuple` function, but in the Sprig source, [`tuple` and `list` are the same function](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/05f1d18231b62a3cc05e4babc33f0f6dbf933f7f/functions.go#L294-L295); calling `list 1 2 3` and `tuple 1 2 3` run the same code and produce identical results.

Neither the Go language nor the Go `text/template` system has "tuple" as a type (unlike, say, Python or Haskell).  I see the references to `tuple` in the Helm documentation, but style-wise, I'd probably always use `list` as a [documented](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions) function corresponding to a standard type.